What is a library that provides the same functionality as Android Beam but in 2024?
I am trying to create an app that works much like the Android Beam contact sharing. Just tap two phones together, and you are provided with the contact information of each other.
It must:

Support either java, kotlin, or dart/flutter
Provide a high-level p2p connection that is easy to send data back and forth through
Not be deprecated or rely on android beam
Completely run as a background service that is easy to set up
Have substantial documentation and/or tutorials associated with it

Preferably:

Works with NFC over any other option

I have not come across anything so far, besides a possible solution by GitHub user underwindfall, called NFCAndroid.
